# Create backup of filesystem

Tags: partitioning, backup, lvm, snapshot

I have LVM set up on my machine with one 8G (gigabytes) swap LV (logical volume) and a ~250G ext4 LV that is the root filesystem. I have installed and heavily configured some software, in the end only 5G of space are used.

I want to **create a backup of the root filesystem** so that I won't have to reconfigure the software all over again in case a clean install is needed because the filesystem is corrupted or there is a problem with the lv containing the root filesystem.

I have thought of:

**Creating a snapshot with lvm**. A possible problem is that I will install many more programs in the future and download a *ton* of files, and all those changes might be too much for a single snapshot to handle.

**Create an .iso image of the LV**. I honestly see no issue with this method, but I don't know how to create an image like this. It needs to have the entire filesystem in it.

**Just copy "/" to a USB stick**. To be frank, I think this is the best option in my case, but I would like to hear an expert's opinion. I have comparatively little experience in what I want to do.

It is very preferable if the backup will be independent, that is, I won't need any special software to use it. E.g. snapshotting is entirely a feature of lvm, so a snapshot isn't independent.

Comment: You can use [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). Supports LVM2.

Comment: You might look at TimeShift. It's in the repos. Google it.